# Adding Padding with React Konva

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I want to create the equivalent of this (sudo code):

```
<div padding="4px">
    <p>My Text</p>
</div>
```

With React Konva elements. I know how to start, using `Group`, `Rect`, and `Text`, **but I can't figure out how to do the padding**. Hope someone can help! Thanks!!

EDIT:
This is what I am trying to build (the green background with 2px padding around the text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [padding property](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Text.html#padding) for text shape to use it.

In order to wrap a rectangle around a text shape, you have to calculate the size of the text.

```js
const App = () => {
  const textRef = React.useRef();
  const [size, setSize] = React.useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSize({
      width: textRef.current.width(),
      height: textRef.current.height()
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        <Group x={20} y={50}>
          <Rect
            width={size.width}
            height={size.height}
            fill="red"
            shadowBlur={10}
          />
          <Text
            text="Some text on canvas"
            ref={textRef}
            fontSize={15}
            padding={10}
          />
        </Group>
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-text-with-padding-yh876

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I might be misunderstanding, but what I am looking for is for the red `Rect` (in your demo) to fit the size of the `Text`, with padding making it larger. Does that make sense? I REALLY appreciate your help. You and Konva are saving me right now haha!